# Identify customer drop-off or churn in Pandas data set (not classification)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of the following form:

```
    Company Period  Revenue
0   Apple   2015Q1  10.0
1   Apple   2016Q1  10.0
2   Apple   2017Q1  10.0
3   Walmart 2015Q1  5.0
4   Walmart 2016Q1  5.0
5   Walmart 2017Q1  5.0
6   Walmart 2018Q1  5.0
7   GM  2016Q1  8.0
8   Facebook    2014Q1  9.0
9   Facebook    2015Q1  9.0
```

You can recreate it w/:

```
import pandas as pd 

Company = ['Apple','Apple','Apple','Walmart','Walmart','Walmart','Walmart','GM','Facebook','Facebook']
Period = ['2015Q1','2016Q1','2017Q1','2015Q1','2016Q1','2017Q1','2018Q1','2016Q1','2014Q1','2015Q1']
Revenue = [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0]

d = {'Company':Company, 'Period':Period, 'Revenue':Revenue}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

You can see that for each company, there is recurring revenue, but any given company can cancel that subscription. **These cancellations are what I'd like to find a way to capture across a dataset of many many rows.**

For example, Apple is consistent until 2018Q1 where there would be an expected annual charge. Walmart is current (next expected would be 2019Q1). GM dropped off as of 2017Q1 and for Facebook, 2016Q1.

What is the best way to identify the period of the *first occurrence of these 'missing' charges* for each company across the whole dataset while NOT counting expected charges that are in the future (e.g the Walmart case, there is not drop-off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the code below. If I understand correctly your problem, this may solve it. If not please clarify the problem and I will be happy to correct the solution:

```
dfDropOutDates = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("Company")["Period"].max())
dfDropOutDates.reset_index(inplace=True)
current_quarter = "2018Q1"
dfDropOutDates[dfDropOutDates["Period"] != current_quarter]
```

Comment: This is great. Only adjustment I made was 


```dfDropOutDates[dfDropOutDates["Period"] < pd.Period(current_quarter)]```